# Данные не записываются в двумерный массив char'ов

Tags: c++, массивы

Я пишу игру, и хочу сделать так, чтобы с файла считывались строки записывались в двумерный массив, и затем считывался массив и строилась карта.
Но компилятор данный код не компилирует и выдает такую ошибку - C++ выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением. Как сделать чтобы данный код скомпилировался либо поменять его?
Вот код:

```
std::ifstream file("maps/map.txt");
char Map[35][66];

int main()
{
    char line[66];
    for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
    {
        file >> line;
        Map[i] = line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не используй cha[n], в с++ есть более удобные коллекции, хотя бы array<char, n>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map[i]` - это одномерный массив `char` на 66 элементов. `line` является тем же. В строке

```
Map[i] = line;
```

Вы пытаетесь присвоить один массив другому. Так делать нельзя. Нужно в цикле скопировать данные из одного массива в другой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    file >> line;
    for (int j = 0; j < 66; j++)
    {
        Map[i][j] = line[j]; 
    }
}
```

Но так как у Вас массив `char`, то можно использовать функцию [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) из [`cstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    file >> line;
    strcpy(Map[i], line);
}
```

Или же вообще обойтись без дополнительного массива и читать сразу в `Map`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    file >> Map[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Оператора присваивание для массивов нет. Есть возможность это сделать если массив сделать элементом структуры.

```
# include <fstream>

std::ifstream file("maps/map.txt");

struct  MapLine {
  char  line  [ 66  ] ;
} ;

MapLine Map  [ 35  ] ;

int main()
{
    MapLine line  ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
    {
        file >> line  . line  ;
        Map [ i ] = line  ;
    }
}
```